# How to write mango query in chaincode correctly?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**Problem:**

I have developed a chaincode. And there I have created a function to retrieve all the lands belongs to a particular person. The code looks like this.

```
async nthUsersLands(stub, args) {
    if (args.length != 1) {
      throw new Error(
        "Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting NIC ex: 944999014V"
      );
    }

    let nic = args[0];

    let landsAsBytes = await stub.getQueryResult({
      selector: {
        docType: "land",
        owner: nic
      }
    });

    console.log(landsAsBytes.toString());
    return landsAsBytes;
  }
};
```

But when I invoking this transaction it leaves me to error like this.

> Error: Illegal value for queryvalue element of type string: object
>   (not a string)

Can someone help me to solve this issue? I look for a solution to this problem on the Internet. But I was unable to find out any good solution to this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
let landsAsBytes = await stub.getQueryResult({
      JSON.stringify("selector": {
        "docType": "land",
        "owner": nic
      })
    });
```

The reason is that your query needs to be a string, not an object.

Comment: Cannot use JSON.stringify in there.It is leaving to syntax error.

Comment: Oh yes. Check that nic is a valid object and put docType and owner between quotes. @dwp I updated code.